# CSS combinators in javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css

If `#nav` can be accessed by `getElementById('nav')`
 how do you access a combinator like this: `#nav > ul > li` and put a `.style.float='right'`??

I can't use CSS because I have to run this script after the `.load()` function.

Comment: Even when your `load()` changes the DOM, the static CSS will still be applied. Or am I missing something. Also you tagged jQuery, so: `$('#nav > ul > li').css('float','right');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
document.querySelector("#nav>ul>li").style.float='right';
```

Comment: This will only select the first of the matched elements

Comment: Yes. Depending on the requirement, you can use querySelector or querySelectorAll(to match all the elements).

Answer (score -1):

The [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) methods take selectors as their argument.